# Combine several font tags by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor.net

Please help me!

I`m using Ckeditor HTML text box editor (http://ckeditor.com/) in my system.

When I choose some style for the text, that editor generates several **font** tags for that text

```
<font size="3">
    <font color="#FFFF00">header</font>
</font>
```

But my system is recognized only the format

```
<font size="" color="" face="">
```

Is it possible to change that behavior ?

My main idea is to write javascript onchange method for that editor. In that method I`m going to parse the generated html text and convert it to the necessary format.

Could you please give some advises ? In the wrong case, what is the best javascript solution to parse generated html ?

Thanks for any advises.

Comment: "But my system is recognized only the format ." Does not make any sense. I'd correct it myself, but I am unsure what you meant by it. could you correct that sentence? Ta!

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow didn`t display the html  tag: current: <font size="3"><font color="#FFFF00">text</font></font> Needed: <font size="3" color="#FFFF00">text</font>

Comment: I would say that there isn't a way to do this automatically. It would require some very complex changes to CKEditor to parse and collapse the tags. However, why does your system not recognize multiple tags?

Comment: Because it is an existing system. And now there are a lot off contents stored in the database in the format <font size="" color="" face="">. If I'll change the system behavior to recognize multiple tags, It will be problem with the old records.